# Nextjs13 how to pass context provider from an component to page.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to pass the context provider from my component to root page.js but can't. Here is my folder structure:

```
app
  components
     nav.js
  context
     nav_context.js
  layout.tsx
  page.js
```

my nav.js which is under my component folder

**nav.js**

```
"use client"
import React, {useState } from 'react'
import  SearchContext from '../context/nav_context'
export default function MobileNav() {
   const [HideDiv,setHideDive] = useState({"search_section":true})

return (
    <>
    <SearchContext.Provider value={HideDiv.search_section}/>
    ...whole jsx
    </SearchContext.Provider>
    
    </>)

}
```

here is my nav_context.js which is under context folder

**nav_context.js**

```
import { createContext } from 'react'

export const SearchContext = createContext(null)
```

my root page.js here trying to show or hide other components depending on SearchContext

**page.js**

```
"use clinet"
import Post from './components/Post' 
import Story from './components/Story'
import SearchContext from './context/nav_context'
import { useContext } from 'react' 

export default function Home() {
   const ShowDiv =  useContext(SearchContext) 

  return (
   <>
    {ShowDiv.HideDiv.search_section &&
       <Post/>
       <Story/>
    }
   </>
  )
}
```

**layout.js**

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
       
         <body >
         <MobileNav />
         <DesktopNav/>
      
        {children}
    
        </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only child components of a "Context Provider" are able to receive the context.

Therefore, if you limit the `SeachContext.Provider` for your `nav`, you can not use that context for the whole page.

Solution is to migrate the `SearchContext.Provider` to your root layout.

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
       
         <body >
             <SearchContext.Provider /*...*/>
                 <MobileNav />
                 <DesktopNav/>
      
                 {children}
             </SearchContext.Provider>        
        </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks but how to reflect changes to global if I update the value from my child component? I am updating the value from my component

Comment: good question: simplest solution will be passing a function that changes the value of context to your nav as prop. Otherwise, you can search for "how to change react context value". Stackoverflow has many questions and answers about this.

Comment: actually I don't want to pass it on my root layout because I don't need it for all of my child or page components. just need it for my root page.js. so any better approach to get value from my component then accessing it to my root page.js using use context?

Comment: This is not the way React works. Again the rule of thumbs is like I said at the answer. Back to your case, you are using Next 13 with app dir. This means the root layout is available for all and you cannot deny it. If you want a different "layout" for each "page", consider using `templates` (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#templates). This means migrating `SearchContext.Provider` to `template`.